# Adding hard coded fixed line to d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hope you can help me with this, its almost an identical problem to (which does not appear to be complete, as no line shows):

[d3.js How to add lines to a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230979/d3-js-how-to-add-lines-to-a-bar-chart)

With the difference being I need to create a hard coded reference line for example at 7%.

I've attempted to create the fiddle here, but cannot get the line to show.

http://jsfiddle.net/ComputerSaysNo/sstSe/1/

I imagine it might be done by changing this...?

`bars.append("line")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", function(d,i) { return height - d.average; })
    .attr("x2", 10)
    .attr("y2", function(d,i) { return height - d.average; });`

Many Thanks,

Ryan.

Comment: Don't append it to `bars`, append to `svg`. You also need to set the coordinates properly. http://jsfiddle.net/sstSe/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're appending the line to your `bars` variable, which is the selection for the bars. You need to append the line to the SVG:

```
svg.append("line")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .attr("x1", 0)
  .attr("y1", y(0.07))
  .attr("x2", width)
  .attr("y2", y(0.07));
```

This also sets the coordinates correctly. Remember that you have no data bound to the line, so `function(d) { ... }` won't work.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sstSe/3/). I've also deleted a bunch of unnecessary and broken code.