# How to draw this D3 chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I want to drawing stack bar chart + Line chart + overlap Chart. Like this Pic

[image]

but I use d3 ,I did so only to: code below "Stack chart". I would like to draw this chart with the overlapchart and the line chart attached. I was worried for a month but I do not know. The comment code just below is the code I tried. It did not work at all.

```js
// Setup svg using Bostock's margin convention

            var margin = {top: 20, right: 160, bottom: 35, left: 30};

            var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var svg = d3.select("#test_con")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


            /* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */

            var data = [
                { year: "2006", redDelicious: "30", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "9", pears: "6" ,per: "10" },
                { year: "2007", redDelicious: "12", mcintosh: "18", oranges: "9", pears: "4" ,per: "10" },
                { year: "2008", redDelicious: "05", mcintosh: "20", oranges: "8", pears: "2" ,per: "10" },
                { year: "2009", redDelicious: "01", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "5", pears: "4" ,per: "10" },
                { year: "2010", redDelicious: "02", mcintosh: "10", oranges: "4", pears: "2" ,per: "10" },
                { year: "2011", redDelicious: "03", mcintosh: "12", oranges: "6", pears: "3" ,per: "10" },
                { year: "2012", redDelicious: "04", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "8", pears: "1" ,per: "10" },
                { year: "2013", redDelicious: "06", mcintosh: "11", oranges: "9", pears: "4" ,per: "10" },
                { year: "2014", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "13", oranges: "9", pears: "5" ,per: "10" },
                { year: "2015", redDelicious: "16", mcintosh: "19", oranges: "6", pears: "9" ,per: "10" },
                { year: "2016", redDelicious: "19", mcintosh: "17", oranges: "5", pears: "7" ,per: "10" },
            ];

            var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;


// Transpose the data into layers
            var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["redDelicious", "mcintosh", "oranges", "pears"].map(function(fruit) {
                return data.map(function(d) {
                    return {x: parse(d.year), y: +d[fruit]};
                });
            }));


// Set x, y and colors
            var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
                .rangeRoundBands([10, width-10], 0.02);

            var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {  return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; });  })])
                .range([height, 0]);

            var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574"];


// Define and draw axes
            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left")
                .ticks(5)
                .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
                .tickFormat( function(d) { return d } );

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom")
                .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);


// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment
            var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "cost")
                .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

            var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
                .data(function(d) { return d; })
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
                .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
                .on("mousemove", function(d) {
                    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
                    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
                    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
                    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
                });


      


// Draw legend
            var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
                .data(colors)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "legend")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")"; });

            legend.append("rect")
                .attr("x", width - 18)
                .attr("width", 18)
                .attr("height", 18)
                .style("fill", function(d, i) {return colors.slice().reverse()[i];});

            legend.append("text")
                .attr("x", width + 5)
                .attr("y", 9)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .style("text-anchor", "start")
                .text(function(d, i) {
                    switch (i) {
                        case 0: return "Anjou pears";
                        case 1: return "Naval oranges";
                        case 2: return "McIntosh apples";
                        case 3: return "Red Delicious apples";
                    }
                });


// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
            var tooltip = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "tooltip")
                .style("display", "none");

            tooltip.append("rect")
                .attr("width", 30)
                .attr("height", 20)
                .attr("fill", "white")
                .style("opacity", 0.5);

            tooltip.append("text")
                .attr("x", 15)
                .attr("dy", "1.2em")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", "12px")
                .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

```css
  svg {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
        }

        path.domain {
            stroke: none;
        }

        .y .tick line {
            stroke: #ddd;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="test_con"></div>
```

Comment: // console.log("dsdasd");
            // var rect2 = groups.selectAll("rect2")
            //     .data(data,function(d) { return d; })
            //     .enter()
            //     .append("rect2")
            //     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
            //     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
            //     .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
            //     .attr("width", function(){ return  x.rangeBand()/2 })
            //     .attr("transform", function(d) { return  x(d.x) });

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230979/d3-js-how-to-add-lines-to-a-bar-chart

Comment: @mkaatman this code can't used that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a total for each object:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.total = d3.sum(Object.keys(d).splice(1, 4).map(function(e) {
        return +d[e]
    }));
})
```

Then, use that total in a line generator:

```
var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return x(parse(d.year)) + x.rangeBand() / 2
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.total)
    });
```

Finally, append the line:

```
var line = svg.append("path")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("d", lineGenerator(data))
```

Here is the demo:

```js
// Setup svg using Bostock's margin convention

var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 160,
  bottom: 35,
  left: 30
};

var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#test_con")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


/* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */

var data = [{
  year: "2006",
  redDelicious: "30",
  mcintosh: "15",
  oranges: "9",
  pears: "6",
  per: "10"
}, {
  year: "2007",
  redDelicious: "12",
  mcintosh: "18",
  oranges: "9",
  pears: "4",
  per: "10"
}, {
  year: "2008",
  redDelicious: "05",
  mcintosh: "20",
  oranges: "8",
  pears: "2",
  per: "10"
}, {
  year: "2009",
  redDelicious: "01",
  mcintosh: "15",
  oranges: "5",
  pears: "4",
  per: "10"
}, {
  year: "2010",
  redDelicious: "02",
  mcintosh: "10",
  oranges: "4",
  pears: "2",
  per: "10"
}, {
  year: "2011",
  redDelicious: "03",
  mcintosh: "12",
  oranges: "6",
  pears: "3",
  per: "10"
}, {
  year: "2012",
  redDelicious: "04",
  mcintosh: "15",
  oranges: "8",
  pears: "1",
  per: "10"
}, {
  year: "2013",
  redDelicious: "06",
  mcintosh: "11",
  oranges: "9",
  pears: "4",
  per: "10"
}, {
  year: "2014",
  redDelicious: "10",
  mcintosh: "13",
  oranges: "9",
  pears: "5",
  per: "10"
}, {
  year: "2015",
  redDelicious: "16",
  mcintosh: "19",
  oranges: "6",
  pears: "9",
  per: "10"
}, {
  year: "2016",
  redDelicious: "19",
  mcintosh: "17",
  oranges: "5",
  pears: "7",
  per: "10"
}];

data.forEach(function(d){
 d.total = d3.sum(Object.keys(d).splice(1,4).map(function(e){
   return +d[e]
  }));
})

var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;

// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["redDelicious", "mcintosh", "oranges", "pears"].map(function(fruit) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: parse(d.year),
      y: +d[fruit]
    };
  });
}));

// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width - 10], 0.02);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d, function(d) {
      return d.y0 + d.y;
    });
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);
  
var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d){return x(parse(d.year)) + x.rangeBand()/2})
  .y(function(d){return y(d.total)})
  .interpolate("monotone")

var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574"];


// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d
  });

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);


// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors[i];
  });

var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.y0 + d.y);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    tooltip.style("display", null);
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    tooltip.style("display", "none");
  })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });

var line = svg.append("path")
 .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("d", lineGenerator(data))

// Draw legend
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")";
  });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors.slice().reverse()[i];
  });

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    switch (i) {
      case 0:
        return "Anjou pears";
      case 1:
        return "Naval oranges";
      case 2:
        return "McIntosh apples";
      case 3:
        return "Red Delicious apples";
    }
  });


// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");

tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

```css
svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

path.domain {
  stroke: none;
}

.y .tick line {
  stroke: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="test_con"></div>
```